# iOS debugging/NSLog monitoring from C#

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, adb, nslog

I've been working with Android for a while, but now my company wants to provide the same solution for iOS as we do for android.  To do this I need to be able to get log messages from the phone to my c# application or something that can bridge between the two.  In android this was relatively simple, using adb monitor logcat output and send intents through the shell to the application, done.

From what I can tell there is no adb corollary for ios (of course, it's apple, right?).  So, does anyone know any way to monitor NSLog messages from and send messages to a physical IPhone via c# or anything that can easily communicate to/from c#?

I would like to have something very similar to adb or more preferably an API dll to reference, but again this is apple so from what I can tell most everything is embedded into their applications and not for public use.

Comment: I think you're missing one important piece of detail in your question:  what are you using to run C# code on your iOS device?  Monotouch or?

Comment: Currently the plan is to write a traditional iOS application using Xcode.  The PC would be running the C# application that needs to communicate to the phone application giving it commands and reading data.  Thanks for the reply btw!

Answer (score 0):

By default, all NSLog statements get routed to Apple System Log (ASL), which is Apple's version of syslog. ASL can be queried using C functions (see asl_set_query, asl_search, and aslresponse_next).

Comment: Okay that's good information, but what is the communication interface between the PC and the phone where these logs are stored?  That is the real question here, although as I said, this is good to know.

Comment: that is still a little hackie.  I would create a simple restful API on the PC and stuff that should be logged would be sent to the restful endpoint.  That way both platforms would have the same interface to your c# app.

Comment: AFAIK the iOS version of ADB is not documented. Personally I would just post the log to a web service using your own code (no wires required). Here's some code for reading the log: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/accessing-the-ios-system-log/